# Qr Code Generator for Pdf file

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, windows-7, software-center

Can A pdf file which contains icons, links, and text be used to generate QR code ? If yes, do we have any software in Ubuntu 12.04 repository, or are there any online solution for this problem ?

As a background, I will generate a qr code of a pdf which is at most 3 page, and use it in the docs file and then create pdf of this docs and, for offline usage, share two file as one.

Answer (score 0):

for what I know, QR codes can be Text, URL, call, SMS, Email, Map, Bookmark, paypal, facebook or contact
also some qr code generator allow you to change colors and some other things to make QR beautiful :)
so you cant convert PDF to QR Code, so if you want to convert any of above to qr visit :

[Online QR Code Generator](http://www.qrzilla.com/)